# how to train the text importing from xlsx file using python classifier as SVM..?/

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm

I have already imported the data using the following code but the problem is how to use it to implement `svm`.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
 import nltk        
 rb = open_workbook('/Users/tejeshwar/Downloads/Defect-Data.xlsx')    
 sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)

 data = ()    
 for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): #train using 500
     temp,add = (),()
     desc,cat = 0,0 #trial
     for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols):       
         if col_index==2:
             #print col_index
             desc = sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value
             #print desc
             #print cellname(row_index,col_index)
             desc = "'" + desc
             #temp +=(desc,)
             #print temp
         elif col_index==5:
             #print col_index
             cat = sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value
             #print cat
             #print cellname(row_index,col_index)
             cat = "'" + cat + "'"
             add = add + (desc,cat)
             #print (add)
         data = data + (add,)

 print 'done'
 training_data = list(data)`
```

where desc is the description and cat is category

And i have to train the model in a manner if give the description it should predict or classify it to category

Comment: Too broad. But you can use this: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

Comment: After trying to use the tool you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: try to use sklearn.svm SVC http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html